How to start timer in actor for in swift 6
I want to use a timer in a background thread to do something like ping in swift 6.
Here is the code:
actor TimerActor {
    var timer: Timer?
    
    func start() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            Task {
                await self.ping()
            }
        })
        RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    func ping() {
        print("send ping")
    }
}

usage
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let actor = TimerActor()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Task {
            await actor.start()
        }
    }
}

The ping() isn't called at all. How to achieve it, thanks!

I came across this as I have a similar issue but I think in general actor (concurrent) context has no information on RunLoop so won't work. I found this which explains but is a little old so not sure if newer recommendations available yet. https://wadetregaskis.com/performing-a-delayed-and-or-repeating-operation-in-a-swift-actor/

In order for your timer to run in background thread, you need to call RunLoop.current.run()
Here is Apple's document about this function:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1412430-run
Here, I create a timer in background thread at ViewController's viewDidLoad and will call ping funcion of actor every 2 seconds
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let actor = TimerActor()
    var timer: Timer?
    
    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.timer = Timer(timeInterval: 2, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                Task {
                    await self.actor.ping()
                }
            })
            RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: .common)
            RunLoop.current.run()
        }
        
    }
}

actor TimerActor {
    var timer: Timer?
    var c = 0
    
    func ping() {
        print("send ping")
    }
}

Also, If you add Runloop.current.run() in actor context, it will cause that actor deadlock as reference in this blogpost:
https://wadetregaskis.com/performing-a-delayed-and-or-repeating-operation-in-a-swift-actor/
